# Why do portions of this Python code not execute

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and am trying to make use of it to parse and manipulate data from a CSV file.  In my script below there are portions of code that are not executing.  However it seems to me that they should unless I am misunderstanding something pretty fundamental about Python syntax.  Please see the comments in the code.  I indicated using the comments what code is not firing.  Can someone tell me what the problem might be?

```
import csv
import datetime

def uniqueify(file):
    checked = []
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        if row[1] not in checked:
            checked.append(row[1])
    return checked


f = open('d:/test.csv')
reader = csv.reader(f)
print "Parsed file is:", f.name

offers = uniqueify(f)

print "Offers", "|",
print "Channel", "|",

start = datetime.date(2011, 12, 01)
end = datetime.date(2012, 01, 31)
d = start
while (d<=end):
    print d, "|",
    d += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
print #force to new line

for o in offers:
    print o,"|", "DRTV","|"
    for row in reader:
#NOTHING INSIDE THIS FOR LOOP EXECUTES
        print row
        if row[1] == o:
            print "foo"
            date = datetime.date(row[0])
            padding = date - start
            print padding

#NOTHNG BELOW THIS LINE EXECUTES
for row in reader:
    print row
    print "foo"
```

Comment: Can we see what your input file is like? Is it possible that it's not actually valid CSV and so there's nothing to read?

Comment: Unfortunately no because it contains sensitive data.  However I suspect there is nothing wrong with the CSV since I successfully parse it and print its contents elsewhere in the code.  For example, my uniqueify function executes and the offers variable prints to screen just fine.

Comment: Provide a scrubbed representative sample.  Also, your print statements look... odd.  Is there any reason you are implicitly concatenating string literals instead of having a single literal?  Also, for message correctness, "Parsed File:" should probably be "Now parsing ".

Comment: @sr2222 Yes I need to clean up those print statements.  Sloppy beginner mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding a

```
f.seek(0)
```

after you call `uniqueify(f)`. I think you're exhausting the file object that is backing the CSV reader.

Comment: Yes that worked.  But I'd love to understand why.  Can you please elaborate on what you mean by "exhausting the file object"?

Comment: Yup.  Instead of trying to reloop over the file contents, you already have parsed content.  Just loop over offers.

Comment: @hughesdan The file object is an iterator with a cursor, you can't iterate over it twice without moving the cursor back.  Once you read a line, you can't read it again, once you've read the whole file, you have to seek the cursor back to the start to read it again.  Or, just reprocess the already read data.

Comment: Thanks @sr2222.  That makes sense.  +1 for the explanation.

Comment: In fact, I suspect (just based on the names) you want to treat the already-`uniqueify`'d data as CSV, rather than reading the entire file as such... yes?